# Trouble attaching to a javascript window with Watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to Watir, and am working on developing a testing tool for my work.
I have run into a problem that I cannot seem to solve, even after checking several sites.

The javascript window creation is below: (the window created holds a pdf in a window, so the only "buttons" are the minimize, maximize, close)

```
<a id="LogIn_HyperLink2" class="ms-WPTitle" onclick="javascript:var win = new Window({className: 'spread', title: 'Security Statement', top:0, left:1, width:750, height:365, url:'--redacted--/security.pdf', showEffectOptions: {duration:1.0}}); win.setConstraint(true, {left:10, right:20}); win.showCenter(); return false;" href="--redacted--/security.pdf" style="color:#6699cc; font-weight:bold;">Security Statement</a><br>
```

I have tried using both

```
puts browser.modal_dialog(:title, "Security Statement").exists?
puts browser.javascript_dialog.exists?
```

both have returned 'false'

What approach should I be taking to attach to this new window, or more directly:  How can I close this new window?

You can see the page at this [link](https://test.domaonline.com/test/) (IE only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the window holds a PDF file it's a browser window, not a modal javascript popup (alert, confirm, prompt)

It's defined to start without all the normal menus etc active, but it's still a browser window.  You can attach to it as described in [the Watir Wiki section about new browser windows](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/New+Browser+Windows),  using the url or the title since you know both of those (given the HTML you showed us).

If you are using Watir-Webdriver use it's window switching commands.  Right now the [watirspec](https://github.com/jarib/watirspec/blob/master/window_switching_spec.rb) for that is your best reference to the methods supported and how they work.

**EDIT**
 Thanks for the link.  While the above would be true for a new browser window, that's not what you are faced with. What you have there is all inside the browser HTML, created in the DOM on the fly with javascript.  It's all standard HTML elements, easily interacted with once you know what's going on (this is actually IMHO easier to deal with than a popup or separate window)

Use the IE developer tools, after you click the link that makes that 'window' appear, click the icon in the toolbar of the dev tools to refresh the DOM in the dev tools and you will be able to see that.

The outermost container appears to be a div of class 'dialog', which is unique in the DOM at that point.

The window controls are three divs under that one, with classes 'spread_close', 'spread_minimize', 'spread_maximize'.  There are three tables that hold the graphic elements for the top, sides, and bottom of the 'window' but there is ZERO actual content there, it's just a visual windowframe.

There is also an iframe that superimposes that window, which is I think were the content would be (I can't get it to load, maybe because I'm not authorized for it or something)

If you just want to close the window, try this:

```
browser.div(:class => 'spread_close').click
```

Since this is coming into existing due to a bunch of client side JS code you may need to use something like the 'when_present' method after clicking the link before you first start to interact with it.   eg if all you want to do is click the link to open it, and then close it, you'd do something like this

```
browser.link(:text => 'Security Statement').click
browser.div(:class => 'spread_close').when_present.click
```

Comment: I have tried using the `Watir::IE.attach()` methods, with both using the title and the URL, and get "Unable to locate window" exception. [link](https://test.domaonline.com/test/) (IE only) - With the Security Statement link - that is an example of one of the locations.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked a charm using the new info you presented.