# How to use Watir to close the "Webpage trying to close this page" message

Tags: watir

I have been tasked with testing the contents of several pop-ups throughout our application. All the pop-ups are called using something similar to:

```
var win = new Window({ className: "spread", title: "Discussion", 
left: 1, width: 410, height: 300, url: "Discussion.aspx?ID=" + id, 
showEffectOptions: { duration: 0}})
```

Since I have been unable to access the pages through the pop-ups, I have started to directly navigate to the pages. The problem is that the pages are designed to close after processing within the page is completed. (`window.close();`)

When testing the pages, since I am directly accessing the page, I get the `The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window.  Do you want to close this window?` message.

Is there a way using Watir (not Watir-webdriven) to access the message and click Yes or No?

PS - (Using IE8 if that matters. I have attempted to find ways to disable the message, but to no avail)

**UPDATE**
Using IE Developer Tools, the generalized html structure with a popup looks like:

```
<html><body>
  <iframe><form>... (Main page here)
  <div class="dialog">
    <div class="spread_close" onclick="Window.close()"/> 
    <table><tr><td><iframe>  (table is not part of the "spread_close" div)
      <html><body><form><div><table><tr><td>
        <textarea name="txtDiscussion" id = "txtDiscussion" >
```

using `browser.div(:class => "spread_close").exists?` returns `true`.

using `browser.text_field(:name => "txtDiscussion").exists?` returns `false`.  I assume this is because of the dual `<html>`.

Comment: Might I suggest trying to solve the accessing the pages through the popup problem instead? I have found that often easier than trying to click these error messages.

Comment: What version of Watir are you using?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 
Watir 2.0.4
I have tried to get access to the popups before and with help was able to get access to be able to close the popups (thanks to @ChuckvanderLinden), but even with the help, was unable to successfully access the fields and buttons **inside** the popup window. ("Popup" might not be the best term, but the best I know for the situation) ... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681869/trouble-attaching-to-a-javascript-window-with-watir) (link to previous question regarding closing the popups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got frames.  That's likely what is blocking access, odds are these are not actually a popup but a 'lightbox' div that uses styles and such to look a lot lie a popup or modal dialog.

Look up the stuff on how to deal with frames on the watir wiki and you should be on your way.